# How can eval handle a function in this way

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to see how the data vs code substitution works when using something like `eval` in a function that lets me pass in any of the print commands like `print` `princ` etc and some text and it uses that command in its output:

```
(defun print-test (fn text)
  (eval '(fn 'text)))
```

I've tried various ways but I can't get this to run. I also tried:

```
(defun print-test (fn text)
  (eval ('fn 'text)))
```

..and other variations. So I'm clearly missing something. I'd like to be able to do this:

`(print-test 'princ 'some-text)`

I typically get an error `fn is undefined`. But since I am evaluating the code in real time, I would think it can get `fn` from my input?

I realize there are other ways to do this, like passing in an actual function object like `#'princ` but I'm curious how the `eval` mechanism works for generating code on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An error like `fn is undefined` isn't telling you that `princ` is undefined, but that the symbol `fn` doesn't have a function binding.  You don't want to call the symbol `fn`, you want to call the *valu* of the variable `fn`.

It looks like you want to evaluate a list whose first element is the value of `fn` and whose second element is the value of `text`.  You'd create such a list using the function `list` in `(list fn text)`.  Then can you call `eval` with it:

```
(defun print-test (fn text)
  (eval (list fn text)))
```

You could also use the backquote notation, and do

```
(defun print-test (fn text)
  (eval `(,fn ,text)))
```

In these cases, if you want to have the same effect as `(princ 'hi)`, you need `fn` to be the symbol `princ` and `text` to be the *list* `'hi` (yes, the list, since `'hi` is shorthand for `(quote hi)`).  You'd call like this, then:

```
(print-test 'princ ''hi)
```

If the second argument ought *always* to be quoted in the generated text, you could could also any of the following:

```
(eval `(,fn ',text))
(eval `(,fn (quote ,text)))
(eval (list fn (list 'quote text)))
```

All that said, though, this seems like a very strange way to be using `eval`.  Unless there's some particularly good reason for it, why not just use `funcall`?  After all, if `fn` is legal as the car of a form to evaluate, and `text` is an argument, couldn't this simply be the following?

```
(defun print-test (fn text)
  (funcall fn text))
```

This would be called a little bit differently, of course. Here, if you wanted the same effect as `(princ 'hi)`, you'd simply pass the symbols `princ` and `hi`:

```
(print-test 'princ 'hi)
```

Comment: I realize it is a trivial example but I'm trying to understand how eval works. However I still get errors when trying to use your version: `(print-test 'princ 'hi)` `The variable HI is unbound.`

Comment: @OpenLearner Isn't that what you'd expect if you tried to evaluate `(princ hi)`?  When I enter `(princ hi)` in the REPL, I get `hi is undefined`.  I'd expect `eval` to give me the same thing.

Comment: I'd be trying to evaluate `(princ 'hi)` so `hi` needs to be passed in yet still quoted

Comment: @OpenLearner If you want to generate the code `(princ 'hi) == (princ (quote hi))`, then you'd need `fn` to be the symbol `princ` and `text` to be the list `'hi == (quote hi)`.  So you'd do `(print-test 'princ ''hi)`.

Comment: okay, interesting. Also, why is `(list fn text)` required and `'(fn text)` not working? This would be the first time I've seen the two not be equivalent

Comment: @OpenLearner I'm not sure what you mean. `(list fn text)` is very rarely equivalent to `'(fn text)`.  E.g., `(let ((fn 1) (text 2)) (list fn text))` returns `(1 2)`, but `(let ((fn 1) (text 2)) '(fn text))` returns `(fn text)`. `(list fn text)` produces a list whose elements are the values of the variables `fn` and `text`, whereas `'(fn text)` is a literal list whose elements are the symbols `fn` and `text`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Instead of requiring an argument to be doubly quoted, I would move one of the quotes inside the function, giving `(eval \`(,fn ',text)`

Comment: @TerjeD. If the second argument is always supposed to be quoted in the generated `(princ ...)` form, that would work, yes.  I'll update.